# SSRS 2005 unwanted page breaks between subreports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping, subreports

I have a report that has one table with two rows. The first row is just a header, the second is a subreport. The subreport consists of a single table. I want to pass one parameter into the subreport (Fields!patient_id.Value) and have the subreport repeat for every patient id. I have that working, but for some reason it inserts a pagebreak after every instance of the subreport when I look at the print preview, even though it could easily fit four of them on one page. I haven't set anything to insert a pagebreak at any place in the report or the subreport. I do want the page to break, but only when there is not enough room on the page to fit an entire subreport.

I've done enough troubleshooting to be able to say for certain that it is the subreport control or the subreport itself that is causing the problem, not the table. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: It's also important to note that when I preview my subreport, there are no page breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Instead of putting the subreport into the table, I put it into a list with a grouping expression of "=Fields!patient_id.Value".

Answer (score 1):

set the ConsumeContainerWhitespace = True on the Report Properties
default is set to false and it attempts to preserve the blank space next to your table